# How can I combine several elements in columns with all other columns stay the same?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I need help with combining `language` columns into one row, and then drop duplicate columns, just combine two different `language` of the same `Movie`, `year`, and `Id`.

There are more similar columns in the CSV, so please help me figure out a way to combine those.Here is the existing csv:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name1','name2','name3','name4','name4'],
                  'Year': ['1905', '1905','1906','1907','1910','1910'],
                  'Id': ['tt0283985', 'tt0283985','tt0284043','tt3402904','tt3458360','tt3458360'],
                  'language':['Mandarian','Cantonese','Mandarian','unknown','Cantonese','Mandarian']})
```

Where `f` now looks like:

```
   Movie  Year         Id   language
0  name1  1905  tt0283985  Mandarian
1  name1  1905  tt0283985  Cantonese
2  name2  1906  tt0284043  Mandarian
3  name3  1907  tt3402904    unknown
4  name4  1910  tt3458360  Cantonese
5  name4  1910  tt3458360  Mandarian
```

And the result should be like this:

```
   Movie  Year         Id             language
0  name1  1905  tt0283985  Mandarian,Cantonese
1  name2  1906  tt0284043            Mandarian
2  name3  1907  tt3402904              unknown
3  name4  1910  tt3458360  Cantonese,Mandarian
```

So row 1 and 2 are identical except language, we just need to combine them into one row, so does row 5 and 6.
Here's my try:

```
ff = new_f.groupby(by = ['Movie','Year','Id']).agg(','.join)
ff.to_csv("File.csv", index=False)
```

But the output is weird:
All other columns disappeared and `language` is the only column left:

```
language
Mandarian,Cantonese
Mandarian
unknown
Cantonese,Mandarian

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `groupby` sets the grouping keys as index, and you explicitly asked `to_csv` **not to export** the index,

Use `as_index=False` in `groupby`:

```
ff = f.groupby(by=['Movie','Year','Id'], as_index=False).agg(','.join)
ff.to_csv("File.csv", index=False)
```

Or, export the index in `to_csv`:

```
ff = f.groupby(by=['Movie','Year','Id']).agg(','.join)
ff.to_csv("File.csv")
```

*NB. if the intermediate is not useful to you, you do not need to set the `ff` variable, you can directly chain `f.groupby(...).agg(...).to_csv(...)`*

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:
ff = f.groupby(['Movie','Year','Id']).agg(','.join).reset_index()

It should work.